# Should i make one user table or more depending upon their roles in symfony2 and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, symfony

I have the hierarchy where there are different categories of users like

1. Staff Admins
2. Teachers
3. Parents
4. Students

I was thinking to put them all in one database table called `usertable`

But then all categories will their different attributes and then students will also have their parents. SO there will be many to many relationships with own usertable.

But if i make different tables then the login process will be different for different people.

HOw should i go

Comment: I'd created one table for shared attributes (like PK, name, role) and create 1 specific table per role for specific attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the users will all share common details, like username, password, etc., you only need one `user` table for them. You should actually use the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) for this. If different types of users have different sets of unique details, I suggest creating additional tables per user type, and use a foreign key to link users from the `user` table to the new table (perhaps named something like `parent_profile`, `student_profile`, etc.)

In regards to the hierarchy of users, you should be using roles. The Symfony2 [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles) have all the info you'll need on this subject.

If you need to link users to each other, read up on Doctrine 2's support for [one-to-one self referencing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing) and [one-to-many self referencing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing) associations. If you use separate entity classes for user user type, you can use the regular one-to-one and one-to-many association techniques.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the difference between having separate tables with foreign key or using doctrine inheritence.